# How can I filter only plain text files in the TOpenDialog in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need to be able to put text from a file into a memo but that I have that part covered.

What I would like to do is filter only plain text files(.txt; .html; .c; .cs; ect) in the file dialogue

Is there some quick way to do that or do I just manually filter all plain text files?

Comment: You must provide the [filter(s)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenDialog.Filter) yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given in the comment by Andreas Rejbrand is correct.

Here is a code fragment that implement it:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    OpenDialog1.Filter := 'Text files|*.TXT;*.HTML;*.C;*.CS';
    if OpenDialog1.Execute(Handle) then
        Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName)
    else
        Memo1.Lines.Add('**** cancel ****');
end;
```

This code write load the selected file content into the memo.

Comment: Just note that although the `Filter` property is a good start, it is not an absolute solution. File extensions are arbitrary, users can name their files however they want, including using extensions that don't actually match the data. And also, users can easily bypass a filter to force the dialog to accept any file they choose. So, you may need to add extra validation in the `OnCanClose` event to make sure the selected files are actually acceptable for your needs.